# Calculate Median for each group in AWS Athena table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, group-by, amazon-athena, median

Below is the schema for the athena table

[image]

I wish to calculate median for 'parameter_value' group by standard_lab_parameter_name & units. For this I followed link : https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_MEDIAN.html
But on running the query

```
select median(parameter_value) from table_name group by standard_lab_parameter_name, units
```

It throws error

```
 SYNTAX_ERROR: line 1:8: Function median not registered
```

Any help? Or if some alternative query would be great

Comment: Athena is not Redshift

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1291152/simple-way-to-calculate-median-with-mysql) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1342898/function-to-calculate-median-in-sql-server) might help. Plenty of other solutions available if you just google "sql calculate median"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Athena is based on Presto 0.172 - you can see all supported functions in [AWS DML Queries, Functions, and Operators](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/functions-operators-reference-section.html). I guess you could use `approx_percentile(x, percentage)` or `approx_percentile(x, w, percentage, accuracy)`, see [Presto Aggregate Functions](https://prestodb.io/docs/0.172/functions/aggregate.html):

> Returns the approximate percentile for all input values of x at the given percentage. The value of percentage must be between zero and one and must be constant for all input rows.

```sql
select approx_percentile(parameter_value,0.5) 
from table_name 
group by standard_lab_parameter_name, units
```

Keep in mind that this is a Approximate Aggregate Functions.